# Humanizer gem human validation Rails 4 with Ajax, Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using Rails 4 with Humanizer gem that checks if user is human.
So far so good. But now in one specific form I need to check if user is human before allowing to submit form.

So far I have googled but didn't find any source or idea to do such thing.

**I have done these things:**

Created function that reacts on humanizer answer field, so after typing answer all data is sent to controller to check if that answer is correct.

Data that I am sending to controller for checking is: humanizer question, humanizer question id, humanizer answer.

**My form:**

```
   <%= form_for(@advertisement,:html => {:id=>"new_advertisement","data-parsley-validate" => true,:multipart => true}) do |f| %>


     <%= f.label :humanizer_answer, @advertisement.humanizer_question %>     
     <%= f.hidden_field :humanizer_question_id ,:id=> "humanizer_question_id"%>
     <%= f.hidden_field :humanizer_question , :value=>@advertisement.humanizer_question, :id=> "humanizer_question"%>                  
     <%= f.text_field :humanizer_answer, :'data-validate_humanizer' => '/blocked/checkhumanizer',:'data-parsley-conditionalrequired'=>'["[name=\"paid\"]:checked", "false"]',:'data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class' =>""%>  

 <button type="submit" class="blue-button btn btn-default" style="width:380px !important;"><%= t('add') %></button>
```

**Script:**

```
$( '[data-validate_humanizer]').blur(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $.get($this.data('validate_humanizer'), {
            question_id: $('#humanizer_question_id').val(),
            question: $('#humanizer_question').val(),
            answer: $(this).val()

        }).success(function() {

            alert("sucess");

        }).error(function() {

            alert("Error");

        });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
def checkhumanizer
       if params[:question_id].present? && params[:question].present? && params[:answer].present?

          render :nothing => true, :status => 200
       else
           render :nothing => true, :status => 404
       end

   end
```

Routes:

```
 resources :blocked do
        collection do
           get 'checkhumanizer'
        end
end
```

**Note**: So far I have everything I should need to make a validation.But I have not a single idea to start with.

**Possible solution**: Is it possible to access humanizer locales where all questions and answers are located ? Is it a good approach or bad?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, using the humanizer methods in your model

```
def checkhumanizer
  if params[:question_id].present? && params[:answer].present?

    ad = Advertisement.new
    ad.humanizer_question_id = params[:question_id]
    ad.humanizer_answer = params[:answer]

    if ad.humanizer_correct_answer?
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    else
      render :nothing => true, :status => 404
    end

  else
    render :nothing => true, :status => 404
  end

end
```

Comment: sandro d. Thanks, Works perfectly.